# SQL Delete statement using JOIN

Tags: mysql

I need to DELETE rows from a MySQL table based on a JOIN.

Table 1 - players

```
id      gang
--------------
1       5
2       8
3       0
```

Table 2 - actions

```
id      player
----------------
1       2
2       1
```

I need to (pseudo code)

```
DELETE FROM 'actions' WHERE player=(SELECT id FROM players WHERE gang=5)
```

So it checks through actions table and if it finds a player that is in gang 5 it removes the entry.

Sorry if I'm not making sense

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

```
DELETE  a
FROM    Actions a
        INNER JOIN Players b
            ON a.player = b.ID
WHERE   b.gang = 5
```

Comment: `JOINs` are much faster than `IN` especially in `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM 'actions' WHERE player IN (SELECT id FROM players WHERE gang=5)
```